# Mingw32 not recognizing wx-widgets

Tags: c++, mingw, wxwidgets, autoconf, automake

I'm trying to use mingw32 to compile an application for windows32. It has a makefile, and when I normally use `./configure`, it works fine.
However, when I set the host as --host=i686-w64-mingw32, this happens:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-w64-mingw32
checking target system type... i686-w64-mingw32
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for i686-w64-mingw32-strip... i686-w64-mingw32-strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking building for Win32... yes
checking for i686-w64-mingw32-gcc... i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether i686-w64-mingw32-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for i686-w64-mingw32-gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of i686-w64-mingw32-gcc... gcc3
checking for i686-w64-mingw32-g++... i686-w64-mingw32-g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether i686-w64-mingw32-g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of i686-w64-mingw32-g++... gcc3
checking for i686-w64-mingw32-ranlib... i686-w64-mingw32-ranlib
checking for sdl-config... /usr/bin/sdl-config
checking for SDL - version >= 1.2.8... cross compiling; assumed OK...
yes
checking for wx-config... /usr/bin/wx-config
checking for wxWidgets version >= 2.8.9... no
configure: error:
        wxWidgets does not seem to be installed on your system.

        If you think wxWidgets >= 2.8.9 is installed,
        please check that wx-config is in path, the directory
        where wxWidgets libraries are installed (returned by
        'wx-config --libs' command) is in LD_LIBRARY_PATH or
        equivalent variable.
```

What's causing this? As you can see from the successful ./configure, I have wxWidgets 3.0.2 installed. MinGW version 4.0.4-2 is installed. Do these versions work with each other? Obviously wxWidgets is configured and everything because it normally works. I can't figure out why it suddenly can't find wxwidgets just because the host is different.

Config.log file:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by sound-of-sorting configure 0.6.5, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --with-wx-prefix=/usr/i686-w64-mingw32

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = JOHNCENA
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 4.4.0-43-Microsoft
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games
PATH: /mnt/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath_target_3578562
PATH: /mnt/c/Windows/System32
PATH: /mnt/c/Windows
PATH: /mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem
PATH: /mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
PATH: /mnt/c/Windows/System32
PATH: /mnt/c/Windows
PATH: /mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem
PATH: /mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
PATH: /mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft DNX/Dnvm
PATH: /mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn
PATH: /mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Windows Performance Toolkit
PATH: /mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common
PATH: /mnt/c/Windows/System32
PATH: /mnt/c/Windows
PATH: /mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem
PATH: /mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
PATH: /mnt/c/Users/Bendy/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps
PATH: /snap/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2067: checking build system type
configure:2081: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:2101: checking host system type
configure:2114: result: i686-w64-mingw32
configure:2134: checking target system type
configure:2147: result: i686-w64-mingw32
configure:2190: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2258: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2269: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2324: result: yes
configure:2383: checking for i686-w64-mingw32-strip
configure:2399: found /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-strip
configure:2410: result: i686-w64-mingw32-strip
configure:2475: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2514: result: /bin/mkdir -p
configure:2521: checking for gawk
configure:2537: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:2548: result: gawk
configure:2559: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2581: result: yes
configure:2671: checking building for Win32
configure:2676: result: yes
configure:2730: checking for i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
configure:2746: found /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
configure:2757: result: i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
configure:3026: checking for C compiler version
configure:3035: i686-w64-mingw32-gcc --version >&5
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc (GCC) 5.3.1 20160211
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3046: $? = 0
configure:3035: i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/5.3-win32/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../src/configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir='/usr/include' --mandir='/usr/share/man' --infodir='/usr/share/info' --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-silent-rules --libexecdir='/usr/lib/gcc-mingw-w64' --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-tune=generic --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libgomp --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --enable-lto --with-plugin-ld --enable-threads=win32 --program-suffix=-win32 --program-prefix=i686-w64-mingw32- --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --with-as=/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-as --with-ld=/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld --disable-libatomic
Thread model: win32
gcc version 5.3.1 20160211 (GCC) 
configure:3046: $? = 0
configure:3035: i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -V >&5
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3046: $? = 1
configure:3035: i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -qversion >&5
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3046: $? = 1
configure:3066: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3088: i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -g -Wno-unused-local-typedefs   conftest.c  >&5
configure:3092: $? = 0
configure:3140: result: yes
configure:3143: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:3145: result: a.exe
configure:3151: checking for suffix of executables
configure:3158: i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -g -Wno-unused-local-typedefs   conftest.c  >&5
configure:3162: $? = 0
configure:3184: result: .exe
configure:3206: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:3214: i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -g -Wno-unused-local-typedefs   conftest.c  >&5
configure:3218: $? = 0
configure:3225: ./conftest.exe
./conftest.exe: Invalid argument
configure:3229: $? = 1
configure:3244: result: yes
configure:3249: checking for suffix of object files
configure:3271: i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -g -Wno-unused-local-typedefs  conftest.c >&5
configure:3275: $? = 0
configure:3296: result: o
configure:3300: checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler
configure:3319: i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -g -Wno-unused-local-typedefs  conftest.c >&5
configure:3319: $? = 0
configure:3328: result: yes
configure:3337: checking whether i686-w64-mingw32-gcc accepts -g
configure:3357: i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -g  conftest.c >&5
configure:3357: $? = 0
configure:3398: result: yes
configure:3415: checking for i686-w64-mingw32-gcc option to accept ISO C89
configure:3478: i686-w64-mingw32-gcc  -c -g -Wno-unused-local-typedefs  conftest.c >&5
configure:3478: $? = 0
configure:3491: result: none needed
configure:3522: checking for style of include used by make
configure:3550: result: GNU
configure:3576: checking dependency style of i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
configure:3687: result: gcc3
configure:3716: checking for i686-w64-mingw32-g++
configure:3732: found /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-g++
configure:3743: result: i686-w64-mingw32-g++
configure:3814: checking for C++ compiler version
configure:3823: i686-w64-mingw32-g++ --version >&5
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ (GCC) 5.3.1 20160211
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3834: $? = 0
configure:3823: i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=i686-w64-mingw32-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/5.3-win32/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../src/configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir='/usr/include' --mandir='/usr/share/man' --infodir='/usr/share/info' --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-silent-rules --libexecdir='/usr/lib/gcc-mingw-w64' --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-tune=generic --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libgomp --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --enable-lto --with-plugin-ld --enable-threads=win32 --program-suffix=-win32 --program-prefix=i686-w64-mingw32- --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --with-as=/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-as --with-ld=/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld --disable-libatomic
Thread model: win32
gcc version 5.3.1 20160211 (GCC) 
configure:3834: $? = 0
configure:3823: i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -V >&5
i686-w64-mingw32-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
i686-w64-mingw32-g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3834: $? = 1
configure:3823: i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -qversion >&5
i686-w64-mingw32-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
i686-w64-mingw32-g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3834: $? = 1
configure:3838: checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler
configure:3857: i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -c -g -Wno-unused-local-typedefs  conftest.cpp >&5
configure:3857: $? = 0
configure:3866: result: yes
configure:3875: checking whether i686-w64-mingw32-g++ accepts -g
configure:3895: i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -c -g  conftest.cpp >&5
configure:3895: $? = 0
configure:3936: result: yes
configure:3961: checking dependency style of i686-w64-mingw32-g++
configure:4072: result: gcc3
configure:4090: checking for i686-w64-mingw32-ranlib
configure:4106: found /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ranlib
configure:4117: result: i686-w64-mingw32-ranlib
configure:4234: checking for sdl-config
configure:4252: found /usr/bin/sdl-config
configure:4265: result: /usr/bin/sdl-config
configure:4275: checking for SDL - version >= 1.2.8
configure:4377: result: yes
configure:4513: checking for wx-config
configure:4532: found /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/wx-config
configure:4545: result: /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/wx-config
configure:4560: checking for wxWidgets version >= 2.8.9
configure:4675: result: no
configure:4749: error: 
    wxWidgets does not seem to be installed on your system.

        If you think wxWidgets >= 2.8.9 is installed,
    please check that wx-config is in path, the directory
    where wxWidgets libraries are installed (returned by
    'wx-config --libs' command) is in LD_LIBRARY_PATH or
    equivalent variable.


## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_c_compiler_gnu=yes
ac_cv_cxx_compiler_gnu=yes
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=i686-w64-mingw32
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_exeext=.exe
ac_cv_host=i686-w64-mingw32
ac_cv_objext=o
ac_cv_path_SDL_CONFIG=/usr/bin/sdl-config
ac_cv_path_WX_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/wx-config
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_CC=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
ac_cv_prog_CXX=i686-w64-mingw32-g++
ac_cv_prog_RANLIB=i686-w64-mingw32-ranlib
ac_cv_prog_STRIP=i686-w64-mingw32-strip
ac_cv_prog_cc_c89=
ac_cv_prog_cc_g=yes
ac_cv_prog_cxx_g=yes
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
ac_cv_target=i686-w64-mingw32
am_cv_CC_dependencies_compiler_type=gcc3
am_cv_CXX_dependencies_compiler_type=gcc3

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/sound-of-sorting-master/sound-of-sorting-master/acscripts/missing --run aclocal-1.12'
AMDEPBACKSLASH='\'
AMDEP_FALSE='#'
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/sound-of-sorting-master/sound-of-sorting-master/acscripts/missing --run autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/sound-of-sorting-master/sound-of-sorting-master/acscripts/missing --run autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/sound-of-sorting-master/sound-of-sorting-master/acscripts/missing --run automake-1.12'
AWK='gawk'
CC='i686-w64-mingw32-gcc'
CCDEPMODE='depmode=gcc3'
CFLAGS='-g -Wno-unused-local-typedefs'
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX='i686-w64-mingw32-g++'
CXXDEPMODE='depmode=gcc3'
CXXFLAGS='-g -Wno-unused-local-typedefs'
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR='.deps'
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EXEEXT='.exe'
GOT_RESCOMP_FALSE=''
GOT_RESCOMP_TRUE=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/sound-of-sorting-master/sound-of-sorting-master/acscripts/missing --run makeinfo'
MKDIR_P='/bin/mkdir -p'
OBJEXT='o'
ON_WIN32_FALSE='#'
ON_WIN32_TRUE=''
PACKAGE='sound-of-sorting'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='sound-of-sorting'
PACKAGE_STRING='sound-of-sorting 0.6.5'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='sound-of-sorting'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='0.6.5'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB='i686-w64-mingw32-ranlib'
SDL_CFLAGS='-I/usr/include/SDL -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT'
SDL_CONFIG='/usr/bin/sdl-config'
SDL_LIBS='-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lSDL'
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP='i686-w64-mingw32-strip'
VERSION='0.6.5'
WX_CFLAGS=''
WX_CFLAGS_ONLY=''
WX_CONFIG_PATH='/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/wx-config'
WX_CPPFLAGS=''
WX_CXXFLAGS=''
WX_CXXFLAGS_ONLY=''
WX_LIBS=''
WX_LIBS_STATIC=''
WX_RESCOMP=''
WX_VERSION=''
WX_VERSION_MAJOR=''
WX_VERSION_MICRO=''
WX_VERSION_MINOR=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE='#'
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCXX_FALSE='#'
am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
am__include='include'
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep='_no'
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='unknown'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='i686-w64-mingw32'
host_alias='i686-w64-mingw32'
host_cpu='i686'
host_os='mingw32'
host_vendor='w64'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /home/sound-of-sorting-master/sound-of-sorting-master/acscripts/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
runstatedir='${localstatedir}/run'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='i686-w64-mingw32'
target_alias=''
target_cpu='i686'
target_os='mingw32'
target_vendor='w64'

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "sound-of-sorting"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "sound-of-sorting"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.6.5"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "sound-of-sorting 0.6.5"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "sound-of-sorting"
#define VERSION "0.6.5"

configure: exit 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to cross-compile from Linux to Windows. For this to work, you need a *Windows* version of wxWidgets and not the native Linux one which is found in your first example.

Do you actually want to cross-compile? Your phrase about "just because the host is different" leaves a doubt about whether you actually do it intentionally.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to cross compile. Does this mean I need to do this from windows, or is there a different build of wx-widgets that I'm missing? I was under the impression that the only packages I needed were the libwxbase and libwxgtk packages.

Comment: You need to cross-compile the wxWidgets libraries first, the packages you list are native libraries and can't be used when cross-compiling.

Comment: I cross compiled the wx widgets using mingw32 for both 32 bit and 64 bit windows and ran make and make install, and yet it still won't recognize it. I've also tried using --with-wxdir and --with-wx-prefix for configure.

Comment: I used ./configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --with-wx-prefix=/usr/i686-w64-mingw32. It finds the config file but still says it's not installed.

Comment: Look in `config.log` for the details of the failing test.

Comment: I've edited the main post to include the contents of config.log

Comment: You need to run `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/wx-config --libs` and see if the libraries returned are usable.

Comment: Ah, this is where the issue lies: `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/wx-config --libs
: not found64-mingw32/bin/wx-config: 18: /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/wx-config:
: not found64-mingw32/bin/wx-config: 21: /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/wx-config:
: not found64-mingw32/bin/wx-config: 22: /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/wx-config:
: not found64-mingw32/bin/wx-config: 26: /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/wx-config:
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/wx-config: 175: /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/wx-config: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")` Why is this happening? It's a clean install.

Comment: No idea but something seems badly wrong with this `wx-config` script, it's definitely supposed to run. Does running it with bash (and not `/bin/sh`) work by chance?

Comment: I'm getting this: `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/wx-config: line 18: $'\r': command not found
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/wx-config: line 21: $'\r': command not found
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/wx-config: line 22: $'\r': command not found
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/wx-config: line 26: $'\r': command not found
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/wx-config: line 41: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''
'usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/wx-config: line 41: `usage()` All of the unexpected tokens are linebreaks.

Comment: It looks like I need to run `dos2unix` on the config file, I'll do that and then try.

Comment: Alright, it recognizes wxWidgets so this is resolved. Now I have sdl issues but that's unrelated.

Comment: It would still be interesting to know why was this file created with DOS EOLs, I have no idea how could it happen under Linux.